# Windows Store Certification: The types in the MainDerp namespace are located in file C:\...\MainDerp.winmd that does not match the namespace

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm trying to publish an app on the Windows Store, but I keep getting this error from the Windows Application Certification Kit (WACK..), preventing me from publishing my app.
The error I get is this:

`The types in the MainDerp namespace are located in file C:\...\MainDerp.winmd that does not match the namespace.`

So I guess it means that the meta-data generated by VS-2012 doesn't match the namespaces found in the project

I tried rebuilding and deleting the suo and rebuilding, all to no avail.
I do get errors if I try to edit my XAML files in design mode, but aside from that, everything compiles just fine.

My project is in C++/CX /XAML.

I have no idea on how to solve this problem; thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Be sure that you're applying the Certification Kit to the Release version of your app, given that the Debug version won't pass the Store Certification.

Comment: What is the actual error message?  You've "bleeped" out the important parts--the name of the WinMD file and the name of the namespace.  The name of the WinMD file must be a prefix of the dot-delimited namespace.

Comment: hmm I haven't really bleeped the name of the namespace neither have I bleeped the name of the file. they match, like MainDerp and MainDerp.winmd.

Comment: Rafael, I am applying the cert tool on the package created by the "create package for Windows Store" menu option.

Comment: If you can provide a small example project that demonstrates the problem, I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: The names of the root namespace in your project should match the name of the winmd file which defines all the types in that project.